# Python dataclass post initialisation for attributes

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

In the documentation for a `dataclass` the following example is given when doing some additional calculations at the initialisation of the instance:

```
@dataclass
class C:
    a: float
    b: float
    c: float = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
```

In the example, the `field` function is called with `init=False`. I'm wondering why this is required, because it doesn't seem to be needed. Have I missed something important?

For example, the following code also seems to work fine:

```
@dataclass
class C:
    a: float
    b: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        self.d = self.a**2 + self.b**2
```

Are there likely to be any problems caused by the second example where the attributes are not defined before `__post_init__` is called? I'm wondering because I'm doing something like the second example, but with many more attributes and with the addition that `b` is an `InitVar`, and I've not noticed any problems yet.

Comment: The second class ``C`` doesn't have an attribute ``c`` or ``d``. Only its instances do. Whether that's a problem or not depends on how much you rely on dataclass being, well, data *classes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case

```
@dataclass
class C:
    a: float
    b: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        self.d = self.a**2 + self.b**2
```

`c` and `d` are available in instance of `C`, but `repr` of said instance does not include that, for example:

```
somec = C(3.0,5.0)
print(somec)
```

output

```
C(a=3.0, b=5.0)
```